# How to verify an integer and prompt user if they enter a non-integer

Tags: c, validation, integer

Here is my code snippet:

```
   while( menuChoice != 5 )
   {
   
   printMenu();

   if( scanf( "%d", &menuChoice ) == 1 )
   {
       switch( menuChoice )
       {
            case 1:
                printf( "Enter origin: \n" );
                scanf( "%s", key1 );
                printf( "Enter destination: \n" );
                scanf( "%s", key2 );
                searchRecords( r, routes, key1, key2, ROUTE );
                break;

            case 2:
                printf( "Enter origin: \n" );
                scanf( "%s", key1 );
                searchRecords( r, routes, key1, key2, ORIGIN );
                break;

            case 3:
                printf( "Enter destination: \n" );
                scanf( "%s", key1 );
                searchRecords( r, routes, key1, key2, DESTINATION );
                break;

            case 4:
                printf( "Enter airline: \n" );
                scanf( "%s", key1 );
                searchRecords( r, routes, key1, key2, AIRLINE );
                break;

            case 5:
                free( r );
                printf( "Good-bye!\n" );
                break;

            default:
                printf( "Invalid choice\n" );
                break;
       }
   }
   else
   {
        printf( "Invalid choice.\n");
   }
}
return 0;
}
```

Everything above works as intended except one small portion and that is when I attempt to validate that an integer is being received.

If used the if scanf statement == 1, that way if it received valid input it can carry on, if not, it goes down to else, the user is notified, the menu comes back and they can try again. The problem I'm running into is that when a non-integer is entered, the "Invalid Choice" is printed to the screen and then the menu comes back, and then it just keeps looping, repeating the phrase "Invalid Choice" and the menu.

How do I prevent this and allow the user to try again? I considered taking the input as a character and then using isdigit. I feel like I'm very close and I'm hoping there's a simple solution that doesn't require me to change a bunch of code.

EDIT: Fixed code that works, thanks! My project works as intended, but I'll always take feedback if things can be optimized!

```
while( menuChoice != 5 )
{
    printMenu();

    fgets( buffer, 10, stdin );

    if( sscanf( buffer, "%d", &menuChoice ) == 1 )
    {
        switch( menuChoice )
        {
            case 1:
                printf( "Enter origin: \n" );
                fgets( buffer, 10, stdin );
                sscanf( buffer, "%s", key1 );
                printf( "Enter destination: \n" );
                fgets( buffer, 10, stdin );
                sscanf( buffer, "%s", key2 );
                searchRecords( r, routes, key1, key2, ROUTE );
                break;

            case 2:
                printf( "Enter origin: \n" );
                fgets( buffer, 10, stdin );
                sscanf( buffer, "%s", key1 );
                searchRecords( r, routes, key1, key2, ORIGIN );
                break;

            case 3:
                printf( "Enter destination: \n" );
                fgets( buffer, 10, stdin );
                sscanf( buffer, "%s", key1 );
                searchRecords( r, routes, key1, key2, DESTINATION );
                break;

            case 4:
                printf( "Enter airline: \n" );
                fgets( buffer, 10, stdin );
                sscanf( buffer, "%s", key1 );
                searchRecords( r, routes, key1, key2, AIRLINE );
                break;

            case 5:
                free( r );
                printf( "Good-bye!\n" );
                break;

            default:
                printf( "Invalid choice\n" );
                break;
        }
   }
    
    else
        printf( "Invalid Choice" );
}
```

Comment: After the invalid input is entered, it is remaining in the input stream. Use `fgets`/`sscanf` combination instead of `scanf`.

Comment: I thought that was the issue. Is there a reason flushing the input stream doesn't work? I did attempt fflush( stdin );

Comment: Its behavior is not defined by C standard. I think Microsoft does define it for its compiler.

Comment: Okay, may be a dumb question, but I've only ever used sscanf when I know what will be inputted. In this case, since it's validation, it could be either an integer or some other random character. So how do I account for that? Obviously if it's an int, I want to put it into menuChoice, otherwise I want to toss it.

Comment: Same way. `fgets` will read a whole line from the input (if it does not exceed the provided buffer length), then you `sscanf`  from this buffer into `menuChoice` same way you do with `scanf` checking its return value.